# Вывод записи из mySQL с сохранением строк

Tags: php, mysql

Проблема заключается в следующем, после добавления записи из textarea в БД форматирование остаётся, т. е. построчно с переносами, но при выводе на страницу вся запись идёт в 1 строку. :( Как сделать вывод с сохранением строк?

Comment: В каком формате данные лежат в бд?
Точнее меня интересует, какой символ отвечает за перенос строки?

Comment: @Aries Данные лежат в varchar

Comment: Вопрос в другом, переносы строк в базе лежат как \r\n или как <br/>?
И сразу, следующий вопрос, данные Вы выводите потом просто как текст на странице, или обратно в какой-то textarea?

Comment: @Николай, изложение проблемы — это не вопрос. внесите, пожалуйста, необходимые коррективы, нажав [edit].

Comment: @aries на первый вопрос затрудняюсь ответить, кажется <br>, а что насчёт вывода, то запись выводится как текст на странице

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если мои телепатические возможности меня не обманывают и я правильно понимаю суть проблемы=) То Вам достаточно воспользоваться функцией `nl2br` при выводе из базы, или же перед записью в базу. Пример:

```
$area = nl2br($_POST['area']);
```

Функция эта перед переводом строки (\r\n, \n\r, \n и \r) вставляет тег `<br/>`.

Answer (score 1):

При выводе из базы, перед тем, как печатать, заверните текст в функцию `nl2br();`